# Extracting a value from an array created by Google Analytics API

Tags: php, arrays

I'm a newbie with PHP so this might be ridiculously easy question, but despite my brave googling attempts I didn't get it sorted out.

I've got an array called $report that looks like this when rendered with print_r:

```
Array
(
    [] => Array
        (
            [ga:pageviews] => 272
            [ga:visits] => 90
        )
)
```

It's created by the googleanalytics.class.php from the XML response. But I fail to extract specific value from it. Using $report[0][0] or $report[0]['ga:pageviews'] returns nothing to me.

I also tried to iterate through it with foreach loop but failed to dig into it. I'm sure this is something super simple, but after few hours of banging my head I hope someone can ease my pain how to extract the pageview and visit values from it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work `echo $report[0]["ga:pageviews"];`

To iterate just use a double `foreach`

```
foreach ($report as $r)
   foreach ($r as $value)
      echo $value;
```

Comment: I assumed the echo method you suggested would work and tried it before, but it echoed nothing. I ended up doing the iteration and then getting the exact data out through if-statements, so it worked, thanks! Would be interested however to understand why the echo didn't work. Heres the var_dump as suggested by Fabrizio:

array(1) { [""]=> array(2) { ["ga:pageviews"]=> string(3) "285" ["ga:visits"]=> string(2) "93" } }

Comment: Well, there was a weird error... the first array key was not 0 but an empty string

Comment: Indeed bizarre, is there a way to directly access that? Tried with [""] but no joy. Will give up and just iterate in about 20 seconds ;-)

Comment: `var_dump($report['']['ga:pageviews'])` should do it

Answer (score 2):

try to do a `var_dump` of the variable, it gives more information, but a simple iteration like the one suggested by Simone should work.  I suggest also to add `{}` to make it easily expandable:

```
foreach ($report as $k=>$r){
   foreach ($r as $k1=>$value){
      echo '$report['.$k.']['.$k1.'] = '.$value."<br />\n";
   }
}
```